# Is it good idea to combine Strategy pattern, Factory pattern, and Chain of Responsibility pattern to avoid if/swich statements?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Is it good idea to combine Strategy pattern, Factory pattern, and Chain of Responsibility pattern to avoid if/swich statements?

In normal situation, strategy context must to contains if or else statements to choose which strategy use. For example:

```
public class StrategyContext {
   @Autowired
   private Strategy defaultSt;
   @Autowired
   private Strategy otherSt;

   public void process(String message) {
       if(checkIfMessageIsFromStackOverflow(message))
            otherSt.doSomething();
       else if(checkIfMessageIsFromAnotherSite(message)) {
            defaultSt.doSomething();
       ......
       ......
   }

   //For example
   private boolean checkIfMessageIsFromStackOverflow(String message) {
       //over 15 lines of code where I parsing some message;
       return otherSt;
   }
   private boolean checkIfMessageIsFromAnotherSite(String message) {
       //over 20 lines of code..
       return defaultSt;
   }
}
```

Of course in practices a if with strategy choose logic are more complicated than only equals. 
I think it is not good solution becouse:

Firstly: In this case context change strategy itself and I think in strategy context should get concrete strategy from outside.

Secondly: if/switch! Every time when new strategy will be created, at StrategyContext we have to add another if statement. I am not a specialist ;) but probably it is breaking the rule of Open/Closed Principle.

I have a idea to extract if statements to chain of responsibility pattern. Each chain element check if object pass as argument to chain, have to be handle be its strategy and return it or invoke another chain element.

So, what do you thnik about it?

Comment: Might be more suited to http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RafiGoldfarb when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: Just in case you find my answer just a bit helpful ... feel free to use your newly gained upvote rights on it ... i am kinda desperately looking for a few more reps today.

Answer (score 3):

A chain of responsibility is a chain where one of the elements of the chain may take its responsibility and respond to the request that it receives.
Generally it implies particular rules to define if the candidate is responsible or not to respond.
Besides in your case you should have two distinct classes to distinguish strategy concern and chain of responsibility concern since the two concerns should not be mixed in the same class if you want to avoid to have too much responsibilities inside them.

When I see your code :

```
    if(strategy.equals("A"))
        defaultSt.doSomething();
    else if(strategy.equals("B")}
        ethoerSt.doSomething();
```

I don't think that adding this complexity be required.
You don't seem to have smart rules that require a chain of responsibility. 
On the contrary I think that a simple factory based on a map with as key an enum or a String and as value a strategy instance could very well do the job.

Comment: Yes, factory with map is good but still I have if statements. I just only gave trivial example but in real case I put some object to StrategyContext and context must decide which strategy use.

Comment: At a time when you add a new class, probabilities are good that you have to change your code to integrate it. If you have to add a `else if` in a factory  when a new Strategy is added is not necessary a problem since you isolate the problem. It would be a real problem if you have to add/remove multiple `else if` scattered in the code when a new Strategy is added/removed

Comment: If your real code is more complex you should show this complexity in your question. It helps to better understand the context and to give a adapted solution. You should probably close or move this question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for good advice, it is very instructive. Referring to your comment. If I create some StrategyFactory and if new strategy will be added I will have to modify StrategyFactory and add new if in StrategyContext. I have edit my code in first post and put more complicated example.

Comment: You are welcome :) With the code you have edited, using a chain of responsibility becomes much relevant. Why don't you post on codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 2):

The real thing here: such if/else/switch things are most often **not good OO**!

What I mean is: don't follow patterns just because you hear of them. Instead look into your **model** and make it more helpful.

Example: don't use plain strings to identify strategies. Give them their own class or even better, an enum. Then you can at least use a more robust enum type switch statement.

Going from there: your strategy context could then use a Map for example:

```
public enum StrategyId { A, B; }

public StrategyContext {
   private final Map<StrategyId, Strategy> strategyById = ...

   public void process(StrategyId id) {
     strategyById.get(id).doSomething();
   }
```

And, as "Woot4Moo 4" suggests: keep in mind that the Strategy must not be a class - that could very well be an interface; allowing you for even more flexibility.

Comment: The other approach to consider is to have an interface that each of the strategies implement so that they could do Strategy.doTheThing

Comment: It is very interesting, but how can I do this if Strategy is Spring component?

Comment: Well, err, maybe then it is not so easy (the interface part); the map doesn't care what "Strategy" actually is.